# ORDER BY en PHP que no ORDER nada de nada

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un query en mysql

Cuando lo realizo a través de PHP simplemente ignora la ordenación como lo necesito (cualquiera sea el campo que intente ordenarlo).

El problema está en PHP por eso paso el código que tengo para llamar a esa consulta:

```
$diaActual = date("Y-m-d");

$sql = "SELECT 
         id, 
         DATE_FORMAT(fec_dde, '%d-%m-%Y') AS fec_dde, 
         DATE_FORMAT(fec_hta, '%d-%m-%Y') AS fec_hta, 
         tit_eve, 
         organiz 
       FROM eventos 
       WHERE (fec_hta >= '$diaActual') 
       ORDER BY tit_eve;";

$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

mucho más abajo cargo una tabla y recorro los datos haciendo:

```
<?php 
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
?>
```

¿alguien puede darme una mano ?

[image: mysql]

[image: php]

la consulta en mysql y la misma consulta con los mismos criterios de ordenación en la pagina php...

[image: ordenacion por titulo]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62007/discussion-on-question-by-mnibor-order-by-en-php-que-no-order-nada-de-nada).

Comment: Qué tipo de campo es `tit_eve` y qué collation usa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te esta faltando la forma en que quieres ordenarlo, DESC o ASC.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
             id, 
             DATE_FORMAT(fec_dde, '%d-%m-%Y') AS fec_dde, 
             DATE_FORMAT(fec_hta, '%d-%m-%Y') AS fec_hta, 
             tit_eve, 
             organiz 
       FROM eventos 
       WHERE (fec_hta >= '$diaActual') 
       ORDER BY tit_eve DESC;";
```

[Aca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3647077/6827438) un ejemplo bueno de como usar la clausula ORDER BY

Comment: si si... el order by no es la primera vez que lo uso... vengo de otros lenguajes y creeme que lo se usar... no entiendo porque PHP lo ignora

Comment: PHP no lo ignora. Debes de tener algo mas que hace que no funcione.